# How to extract "Image" type from SQL Server Northwind database with JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, northwind

I'm unit testing binary data in a sample database and I want to read the image column from the Categories table from northwind sample db and save it to a file.

https://github.com/microsoft/sql-server-samples

I get the byte array fine but if I write it the image file is invalid.  I've read that the format contains an OLE header 78 bytes to remove. I tried that but still the image is not viewable when I save it to a file.  I tried saving as JBP and BMP. Neither worked.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you don't **know** how that image is encoded, you will struggle regardless. Simple search will find ways to download a binary column to a file. Using one of those you could compare the contents with that created by your application. If the same, then you need to solve the "what does the image contain" issue (but at least your app is working correctly). If they are not the same, then your problem is with your application code (and perhaps assumptions about any header or content interpretation). Dont' know what "JBP" is.

Comment: I suggest you ditch the 20+ year old Northwind database and use a newer sample database, like AdventureWorks or WideWorldImporters. Those images are not OLE format.

Comment: @DanGuzman Yeah. Good idea. I was planning on testing with WideWorldImporters anyway.